# Google Web Toolkit - Can't Work

Tags: java, regex, web-applications, gwt

I was experimenting to use this regex pattern checking method as described in

[How to check if a given Regex is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704857/how-to-check-if-a-given-regex-is-valid)

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException

public class RegexTester {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        String userInputPattern = arguments[0];
        try {
            Pattern.compile(userInputPattern);
       } catch (PatternSyntaxException exception) {
            System.err.println(exception.getDescription());
            System.exit(1);
        }
       System.out.println("Syntax is ok.");
    }
}
```

(using Google Web ToolKit) but I keep getting the "failed" message":

> Plugin failed to connect to Development Mode server at 127.0.0.1:9997

whenever I use the `Pattern.compile(String)` method.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See this [previous question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162240/regular-expressions-and-gwt

Comment: @BobV, you can use `[this](link)` syntax.

Comment: @BobV i tried changing it to RegExp as answered by Philippe Beaudoin, but i am still getting the same error.

Comment: sorry, i was using the wrong exception when i changed that. it's solved. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use 'com.google.gwt.regexp.shared.RegExp', instead of 'java.util.regex.*'.

Answer (score 0):

Some characters have special meaning they are known as Metacharacters.
so providing a sample code below.

I will suggest you to visit 
[metacharacters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter) and [java.util.regex.Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

```
String s = "+1234567890PrasadBelhe1234567890";
System.out.println("args[0]:"+args[0]);
if(args[0].startsWith("+")||args[0].startsWith("?")||args[0].startsWith("*")){
    System.out.println("Invalid regex :"+args[0]);//added basic
    System.exit(1);
}
else{
    if(args[0].equals(".classpath")) args[0]=".";//java default
    //Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(args[0]));
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(args[0]);
    Matcher mymacher = p.matcher(s);
    System.out.println("Finding results...");
    while(mymacher.find()) System.out.println(s.substring( mymacher.start(), mymacher.end()));
    System.out.println("Syntax is ok:"+args[0]);
}
```