# AIR, Flex - how to check if regex is valid

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air

i want to check in Adobe AIR if given regex is valid.
I'm looking for somtehing similar like here:  [How to check if a given Regex is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704857/how-to-check-if-a-given-regex-is-valid)

---

I dont want to compare regex and text-value - i jus want to check if this regex is valid. If someone type invalid regex - for example: "x{5,-3}" or "(((^^$$$)//)" or something like this i just need to communicate to him that this regular expression is not valid - its not proper regular expression.

In Java it can be done by:
[code]

```
try {
            Pattern.compile(userInputPattern);
        } catch (PatternSyntaxException exception) {
            System.err.println(exception.getDescription());
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

[/code]

Comment: There should be a regex for this...

Comment: Interesting, AS3 doesn't appear to have this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you are looking for a test app in which you can enter an regular expression and a value and the app will tell you if there is a match or not.  Assuming that is what you want, this code will do it for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function test(regex:String, value:String):String {
                return new RegExp(regex).test(value) ? "MATCH" : "NOT A MATCH";
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Form>
        <s:FormItem label="RegEx:">
            <s:TextInput id="regex" />
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Test Value: ">
            <s:TextInput id="testValue" />
        </s:FormItem>

        <s:Label text="{test(regex.text, testValue.text)}" />
    </s:Form>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: Not exacly - i dont want to compare regex and text-value - i jus want to  check if this regex is valid.

If someone type invalid regex - for example: "x{5,-3}" or "(((^^$$$)//)" or something like this i just need to communicate to him that this regular expression is not valid - its not proper regular expression.

Comment: Gotcha.  I don't see anything in the documents that would suggest that RegEx supports this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dynamicaly see the result of your regexp on a given input, I suggest you this online tool:

[Flex 3 Regular Expression Explorer](http://ryanswanson.com/regexp/#start)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "valid"? If you want to check if the regular expression matches a particular string, you can use `RegExp::test()` - it will return `true` if there is a match, `false` if there isn't.

Comment: I know that - i just want to check if my regex it is not wrong. I need to check that pattern is ok

Comment: I just want to check if regex syntax is valid - not testing regex on example

In Java it can be done by:

try {
            Pattern.compile(userInputPattern);
        } catch (PatternSyntaxException exception) {
            System.err.println(exception.getDescription());
            System.exit(1);
        }

Comment: ok, probrably it cant be done - thats ok - i just wanna know that it can or can not be done

Answer (score 0):

I can't find this implemented in AS3, but here there is the source code Pattern.java

https://github.com/unkiwii/Random-Stuff/blob/master/java/src/java/util/regex/Pattern.java

Maybe you can implement the same in AS3.